# Resource File in Install4j

Tags: install4j

i want to access a Resource file while Installation Process. I added a File as Resource into my Setup. Now i need to access this File while the Setup Porcess.
Is there a way to access the file during installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resource files are extracted to the directory contained in the installer variable `sys.resourceDir` at startup.

If the name of the resource file is `resource.txt`, the full path at runtime is given by

```
${installer:sys.resourceDir}/resource.txt
```